# Why does Doctrine's "NativeQuery" return empty result set?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

If I use Doctrine's `NativeQuery` to execute some exotic PostgreSQL queries, I get empty result set. For example, assume that the following code is coming from a repository class of an entity

```php
// src/Repository/FooRepository.php

class FooRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Foo::class);
    }

    /**
     * @return Foo[] Returns an array of Foo objects
     */
    public function findBySomething(string $something)
    {
        $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();

        $nq = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery(
            'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE column ->> \'key\' = :param',
            $rsm
        );
        $nq->setParameter(':param', $something);

        return $nq->getResult();
    }
}
```

Now, when I call this method from the controller, I get `[]`. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have told Doctrine to return empty result. How? You have instantiated `ResultSetMapping`, but didn't configure it. If you want the result as array of `Foo` object, you need to configure this result set. Add the following lines after `$rsm` instance:

```php
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$rsm->addEntityResult(Foo::class, 'f');
$rsm->addFieldResult('f', 'id', 'id');
```

That's it. Now you'll really get an array of `Foo` object.